# Any ruby gems or APIs out there that contain most English words?

Tags: ruby, api, csv, rubygems

I'm working on a project that is very text-based.
Would be really helpful if we could find a ruby gem, XML library, or even a CSV file that contains most of the words in the English language.

Definitions are not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [wordlist](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Aspell would be a good place to start looking, and there is a ruby binding here:

https://github.com/fauna/raspell